# Open source test automation tools for functional testing of web applications

Tags: testing, open-source, automation

I'm doing Functional test of web application Manually. I like to automate the tests in different browsers (such as FF, Chrome, IE & MS Edge etc.).

Can anybody recommend some good open source test automation tools to test web applications?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Watir** - 'Web Application Testing in Ruby', a free open-source family of web automation libraries in Ruby. The libraries support IE on Windows, Firefox on Windows, Mac and Linux, Safari on Mac, Chrome on Windows and Flash testing with Firefox. Note: Firewatir (targeting Firefox) is now merged with Watir. For a listing of additional tools that are available to extend some capabilities - see the Watir site and also Alternative Tools for Web Testing' page at the OpenQA site for more info.

Here is some more info for the many other testing tools
http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html

Here is the comparison:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), because of its superior handling of JavaScript. Specifically, I would recommend Selenium 2.0 (now available as an alpha version): it has been recently integrated with WebDriver to improve its API, and is consequently much easier to use.

Comment: A late comment, if I may, mostly for other people landing on this page. Selenium by itself is good, but there is much more to a good test automation tool than automating the actions in the browser. Some examples are: reporting, parallelization, test data storage/access, data-driven testing and a ton of others. One might be better off leveraging a tool that provides a solid head start, like [OpenTest](https://getopentest.org) (disclamer: I'm a contributor), to avoid reinventing the wheel and to focus on the important stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)?

It is widely used.

Another well known framework is [Watir](http://watir.com/), using Ruby and its .NET counterpart [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Another option is Sahi http://sahi.co.in/ It is well suited for applications using a lot of AJAX and Javsascript because it does not need any wait statements (automatically waits for AJAX and page loads), automatically locates elements across frames/iframes, has stable smart accessors which do not use XPaths, but rather uses relational APIs like near, in, under etc. It also has recorder/accessor spy for all browsers. It has drivers in Sahi Script (Javascript), Java, Ruby and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

personally i recommend selenium-webdriver. If you want to write your test automation using ruby then you might want to consider watir. The watir api is more simpler to understand and use than selenium-webdriver. You can take a look at few examples I created using different tools. Here are the links

Watir+rspec: 
http://testingandagile.blogspot.com/2011/08/getting-started-with-automation.html

Cucumber+Capybara+selenium-webdriver:
http://testingandagile.blogspot.com/2011/07/cucumber-capybara-webdriver-example-for.html

Answer (score 1):

selenium + testng is my recommendation.
selenium is for APIs that calls javascript to simulate user action on web page.
testng is a test framework like junit, but is also support grouping and multi-thread over large set of test data in table format

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Selenium, then I would also look at TestMaker by PushToTest.com. It is an open source test automation framework that lets you create data driven tests for Selenium and allows you to run the scripts as functional, automated regression and load tests as well as production SLA monitors.  You can download the tool from the website and there is a tutorial to walk you through working with Selenium scripts.

Answer (score 0):

SeLite helps functional testing. It's a framework for Selenium IDE that allows your tests to access (read and write to) a test DB (isolated from the DB of the tested application). See https://code.google.com/p/selite/wiki/ProjectHome.

SeLite is ideal if the web application uses SQLite, because the (separate) test DB is also in SQLite - test that makes data lifecycle very easy. However, you can use SeLite even if your web app uses other type of DB.